# Ag-grid unit testing: check the content of a cell rendered by a CellRenderer

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

How is it possible to check the content of a cell that is rendered by a `CellRenderer` class?

(let's say we got a `CellRenderer` that gets as input a `Date` object and displayes it in some specified format. I would like to be able to check the final value.)

**Note:** The Ag-grid [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-testing-angular/#testing-user-supplied-components) provides only the way of testing with a `CellEditor`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The logic in the documentation you shared is the same, the only difference is that you can get the Cell Renderer instances by calling `api.getCellRendererInstances`.

You can find the documentation for this here: https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/angular/grid-api/#reference-rendering

Once you've got the instance, you can query for the class `.ag-cell-value` which will contain the rendered value (same as the Cell Editor example)